# Decorator pattern - Add methods to an interface

Tags: c#, decorator

I'm currently struggling on the implementation of a IUnitOfwork.
Let's assume that I have an interface that has 2 methods:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity, in TKey>
{

    TEntity Get(TKey id);

    IQueryable<TEntity> All();
}
```

Now, let's say that I have a couple of classes (entities) that implement this interface.
But, it's possible that some entities needs to have additional methods to query, such as a GetById(int id).

This could be easily solved by creating a new interface called, IRepositoryWithGetById

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity, in TKey>
{

    TEntity Get(TKey id);

    TEntity GetById(int id);

    IQueryable<TEntity> All();
}
```

You'll were this is leading up to, a nightmare for maintaining the code.
I was thinking about using the decorator pattern, but I don't quite find a good solution.

Note: I'm using interfaces since I should be able to mock it.

As suggested by a user I'm using interface inheritance, so here's the updated code:

```
public class Wrapper
{
    public IRepository standardRepository = new Repository();
    public IDeleteRepository deleteRepository = new DeleteRepository();
    public ICreateRepository createRepository = new CreateRepository();    
}

public class Repository : IRepository
{
    public void GetAll() { }
    public void GetById(int id) { }
}

public class DeleteRepository : Repository, IDeleteRepository
{
    public void Delete() { }
}

public class CreateRepository : Repository, ICreateRepository
{
    public void Create() { }
}

public interface IRepository
{
    void GetAll();
    void GetById(int id);
}

public interface IDeleteRepository : IRepository
{
    void Delete();
}

public interface ICreateRepository : IRepository
{
    void Create();
}
```

Anyone who know how I can solve this issue?

Comment: what about interface inheritance?

Comment: I've updated my original question to use interface inheritance, but now it means that if I need to have a repository than can do GetAll(), GetById(), Create() then I need to create an class called "DeleteCreateRepository that would implement IDeleteRepository and ICreateRepository. You see what I mean?

Comment: Why not extend the interface using Extension Methods?

Comment: Basically, in repository pattern the very generic interface should have all basic methods than can be implemented by classes or inherited by other interface. Lets say, IRepository<T> is the most generic one then CustomerRepository<T> can inherit from IRepository for all common operations. Regarding, Unit of Work, it generally involves commit logic such as Save.

Comment: Thanks for the information. That's exactely the approach I'm using for the moment.

Comment: God damn can we stop using Repositories. AHHH

Comment: No @KrishnaDhungana a repository should NOT be generic. Repositories should not ASSUME implementation and not FORCE implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution suggested by  KrishnaDhungana works fine. Here is an example as i understand it, using the simple class student as an example. It is easy to construct repositories and to test if you inject into your implementation method...

```
public class Student
{
    int NoOfParties;
    int NoOfHangOvers;
}

public interface IRepo<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    T GetByID();
}

public interface IRepoCreate<T>
{
    Int32 Create();
}

public interface IRepoDelete<T>
{
    void Delete();
}

public interface IStudentRepo : IRepo<Student>, IRepoCreate<Student>, IRepoDelete<Student>
{
    IEnumerable<Student> GetAll();
    Student GetByID();
    int Create();
    void Delete();
    Student GetByParty();
}

public class MSSQLStudentRepo : IStudentRepo
{
    public IEnumerable<Student> GetAll() { \\stuff }
    public Student GetByID() { \\stuff }
    public int Create() { \\stuff }
    public void Delete() { \\stuff }
    public Student GetByParty() { \\stuff }
} 

public class MySQLStudentRepo : IStudentRepo
{
    public IEnumerable<Student> GetAll() { \\stuff }
    public Student GetByID() { \\stuff }
    public int Create() { \\stuff }
    public void Delete() { \\stuff }
    public Student GetByParty() { \\stuff }
}

public void ImplementationExample()
{
    IStudentRepo Repo = new MSSQLStudentRepo();
    var Bob = Repo.GetByParty();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In decorator pattern, additional methods may not come in picture. A decorator pattern means the methods will remain same but the behaviour might change. I am writing a blog on it and I will update this response once done.

The following code might help you as all of the functions can easily fit in a sigle class and you can cast it to respective return repsitory.

```
using System.Linq;

public interface IRepository<TEntity, in TKey>
{

    TEntity Get(TKey id);

    IQueryable<TEntity> All();
}

public interface IRepository
{
    void GetAll();
    void GetById(int id);
}

public interface IDeleteRepository : IRepository
{
    void Delete();
}

public interface ICreateRepository : IRepository
{
    void Create();
}


public class Wrapper
{
    private readonly CombinedRepository standardRepository = new CombinedRepository();

    public IRepository Repository
    {
        get { return standardRepository; }
    }

    public ICreateRepository CreateRepository
    {
        get { return standardRepository; }
    }

    public IDeleteRepository DeleteRepository
    {
        get { return standardRepository; }
    }
}

public class CombinedRepository : IRepository, IDeleteRepository, ICreateRepository
{
    public void GetAll()
    {
    }

    public void GetById(int id)
    {
    }

    public void Delete()
    {
    }

    public void Create()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: still waiting for your blog post :D

Answer (score 0):

I think `abstract` classes work quite well for repositories which need to be mocked, with `virtual` implementations than can be overridden as needed.

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity, in TKey>
{
    TEntity Get(TKey id);
    TEntity GetById(int id);
    IQueryable<TEntity> All();
}

public abstract class Repository : IRepository
{
    public virtual TEntity Get(TKey id) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public virtual TEntity GetById(int id) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> All() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}

public class FullRepo : Repository
{
    public virtual TEntity Get(TKey id) { /*Implement it!*/ }
    public virtual TEntity GetById(int id) { /*Implement it!*/ }
    public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> All() { /*Implement it!*/ }
}

// No GetById here
public class PartialRepo : Repository
{
    public virtual TEntity Get(TKey id) { /*Implement it!*/ }
    public virtual TEntity GetById(int id) { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> All() { /*Implement it!*/ }
}
```

Basically, only implement what you need, with the interface/abstract class exposing everything. This approach is (to me, at least) very readable and easy to extend... and very mockable.

To avoid throwing and instead disallow the usage of the methods, you can use the `ObsoleteAttribute` ([MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/961hff5d.aspx))

```
// No GetById here
public class PartialRepo : Repository
{
    public virtual TEntity Get(TKey id) { /*Implement it!*/ }
    [Obsolete("This method can't be used by this repository", true)]
    public virtual TEntity GetById(int id) { /*Can be empty*/ }
    public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> All() { /*Implement it!*/ }
}
```

Passing `true` makes the invocation of the method a compilation error (VS will say that it's "obsolete" so it wouldn't be exactly correct, but it wouldn't let the method be invoked nontheless).

Comment: I don't like this approach because I will have repos that have a lot of methods that throws a NotSupportedException().

Comment: You could also/instead mark them obsolete to achieve the "This won't work" objective. Expanded the answer to comply.